# if I know screen size on the mobile device how can separate a line of the text

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

If I know screen size on the mobile device how can separate a line of the text in the html page. Text without blanks and punctuation. For example:

"TestthisstringWithTheMobileDeviceNotMoreThan480pixelsAndThisStringCanBeEvenLongerItDependsOnlyOnMyFantasy".

I do it, because I need a method to create a filter and inside the filter can be everything. I hope it is possible, but if it isn't let me know, please. Write me if you have another better decision for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not neccessary to break the string by yourself.
You can use the CSS property word-wrap ([reference at w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp)) to control string breaking.

You seem to be looking for the `break-word` setting that breaks strings
even if there are no blanks.

```html
<div style="width: 100px; word-wrap: break-word;">
  ALongStringThatShouldExceedTheFixedWidthOfThisBox
</div>
```

In fact StackOverflow uses that property to break the long string example of your question.

Comment: Better use other source than w3school. Even if it's getting better, it's still not accurate enough. Maybe change your reference by the [Mozilla Developper Network word-wrap page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)?